# How to change navigation background color section to section with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm creating a navigation bar and i want to change its background color when it scrolls down to different sections.

SEE FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/TTPc9/51/

```
  <header class="topbar">

  </header>

  <section id="section1">
  </section>
  <section id="section2">
  </section>
```

jquery

```
   $(window).scroll(function () {

 var windows = $(window);
 var navigation = $('.topbar');

 if (windows.scrollTop() > 100) {
     navigation.css({
     'background-color':'#eee'
     });
 }
 if($('#section1').scrollTop() > 10)
 {
     navigation.css({
     'background-color':'#FF0000'
     });
 }
 if($('#section2').scrollTop() > 10)
 {
     navigation.css({
     'background-color':'#660066'
     });
 }
 else {
     navigation.css({
     'background-color':'#000'
     });
 }

 });
```

Please don't refer me to use

```
  $(window).scrollTop();
```

because i'm working on a big project and need a better way to fix this issue.so it will be helpful in my future projects thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/26p6Lnm8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/TTPc9/52/)**

```
var t = $('#section1').offset().top - 100;
var t1 = $('#section2').offset().top - 100;
var navigation = $('.topbar');
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > t1) {   
        navigation.css({
         'background-color':'#FF0000'
         });
    } else if($(this).scrollTop() > t) {   
        navigation.css({
         'background-color':'#660066'
         });
    } else {
        navigation.css({
         'background-color':'#eee'
         });
    }
});
```

For more advanced version refer **[here](http://stanhub.com/sticky-header-change-navigation-active-class-on-page-scroll-with-jquery/)**